# Access security between Windows Services with NamedPipe

Tags: c++, security, winapi, service, named-pipes

I have a C/C++ windows service implementation that is deployed on two different servers, using a NamedPipe so that they can communicate with each other.

I followed the least privilege principle, assigning the service account to "NT AUTHORITY/NetworkService", creating the NamedPipe with a Security Descriptor that has 'Read permissions' (A;OICI;GR;;;NS), blocked anonymous access, blocked all built-in guests, Grant all rights to logged users and Administrators group.

The services are giving me an "Access Denied (0x5)" error.

Here are the things I tried:

1. I tried to give all permissions for the "NetworkService" account. I know it is bad :( but just to see whether it works or not!  Access Denied
2. Allowed read permission to Anonymous users (I read that the "NetworkService" account presents anonymous credentials to other computers on the network). Access Denied

The service is working with my console test application :( but not with another services. The security is critical and I just want both servers to be able to communicate with each other.

Can anyone tell me, whether I should create a specific account for each service in both servers?

The servers are not in a Domain, so I am not sure how to create a network wide account, or even if it is possible. I am not so good with Windows administration stuff!

Is this the correct direction to take to get the services to communicate with each other?

Comment: 0x57 is `The parameter is incorrect.` - so what error exactly ? 5 or 0x57 ?

Comment: Sorry it is 0x5. I will fix the question

Comment: Do you HAVE to use a named pipe?  You could use TCP/UDP sockets instead, for instance.  There is no security permissions needed for that, just firewall access (named pipes use sockets over the network anyway).

Comment: It is an option, I already wrote most of the code threading and synchronization etc. Its a last shot to get it work. I just don't feel like to write the whole thing again. I have it working with my console application as client. :(

Comment: if you for test set *DACL* to 0 - so allow full access for any - in this case worked ? and how you login (under which account) from remote comp ?

Comment: both running under the NetworkService account. Do you mean that I should set the PSERCURITY_ATTRIBUTES parameter to NULL ? I tried that. I get the same "access denied"

Comment: no, I mean set *DACL* to 0 in security descriptor

Comment: `SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR SD;
  InitializeSecurityDescriptor(&SD, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION);
  SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(&SD, TRUE, NULL, FALSE);
  SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = { sizeof(sa), &SD };` I mean and are you not connect to `\\server\IPC$` before open pipe ?

Comment: I am creating the Security Descritor with "CovertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor" function. The string I pass is L"D:(D;OICI;GA;;;BG)(D;OICI;GA;;;AN)(A;OICI;GRGWGX;;;NS)(A;OICI;GRGWGX;;;AU)(A;OICI;GA;;;BA)";

Comment: try set *DACL* in it to 0 for test. I paste code - this SD allow all access for everybody

Comment: I just tried it, its just the same. I looked at the security of the service with "sc" tool and it looks like this D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)S:(AU;FA;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;WD). I think I will have to read about what is going on with the services security.

Comment: if with 0 *DACL* client can not connect - task not in your SD but in how client login to server (are you call `NetUseAdd` to `\\server\IPC$` ?) or really use sockets for example

Comment: No I cannot add that. It gives me strange error. System error 67, The network name cannot be found.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have a design issue.

When you wrote "creating the NamedPipe with a Security Descriptor that has 'Read permissions'", the question should be "read permissions *for whom*?". Permissions are always tied to trustees.

In Windows, trustees don't exist in vacuum. They're always defined in some scope. Without a central user database (Active Directory), that would be the local scope of each computer. And two computers have distinct, non-overlapping sets of trustees. `Administrator` on one machine is unrelated to `Administrator` on another.

So when you give `NetworkService` all access to a NamedPipe on one computer, that probably meant you gave the `NetworkService` trustee from that sam computer access. *Not* `NetworkService` from other computers!

Fundamentally, without a Primary Domain Controller to function as a shared authority, [two Windows PC's just won't trust each other](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2009/11/03/the-machine-sid-duplication-myth-and-why-sysprep-matters/). Each is its own security authority.

Comment: I agree with your arguments, but then my question is, how is my pipe client (console application) is running on a different machine can access the same service without a problem.

Comment: @CodeWeed: My first suspicion would be that it actually isn't accessing the service. Would be a bit silly, but such bugs happen.

Comment: It *might* work if you create an account on both machines with the same username and password, give access to that account, and run the service as that account.

Comment: @MSalters What do you mean by "it actually isn't accessing the service". I can connect to the service from my console application across the network. I guess something is blocking the access when it is run in a windows service.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: That sounds like voodoo security. Why would one Windows machine trust another with a password? Remember, passwords are supposedly secret, and user `A\Administrator` is not user `B\Administrator`. So A isn't going to send the password of `A\Administrator` to B.

Comment: @CodeWeed`: I'd double-check if there's actually a network connection, and you're actually seeing data that must have come in over the network.  I.e. you're not by accident reading from a local pipe, or silently failing to read.

Comment: for authentication with password (even with *ntlm* ) not need send password to remote side. and it never send. however remote client before open pipe can connect to \\server\IPC$ and set username\password which it will be used for login remote server

Comment: When you connect to a remote server, Windows will by default attempt to authenticate using your current username and password.  It does so without sending the password, of course, using challenge-response authentication.  (But I've found this to be erratic, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.)

Comment: @MSalters I double checked. I can connect to the NamedPipe instance on the running service. I don't have any other instance running.